# Como ler tags dentro de uma string?

Tags: html, .net, string, razor, html-tags

Eu estou desenvolvendo um código em .NET Core Razor Pages, e em uma parte, eu gostaria de criar uma lista de itens, de acordo com dados que eu já estou pegando la...

**Meu Código:** (Arquivo.cs)

```
var descr = "<ul>";

for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
     descr += "<li>" + result.vfp.descricao[i].desc + "</li>";
}
descr += "</ul>";

HttpContext.Session.SetString("xmltojson", descr);
```

(Arquivo.cshtml):

```
<div class="card menu-card">
    <div class="card-body">
         <center><h4> @HttpContext.Session.GetString("xmltojson")</h4></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**RESULTADO:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele está escrevendo as tags, ao invés de montá-las, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `@Html.Raw(HttpContext.Session.GetString("xmltojson"))` não seria assim?

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar uma string e renderizar como HTML utilize o @Html.Raw do Razor.

Exemplo:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpContext.Session.GetString("xmltojson"))
```

Comment: acho que faltou alguma coisa no seu exemplo

Comment: @SamuelMachado editei a questão corrigindo o exemplo.